# Alphabet order in index and index spacing

Tags: indexing, makeindex, alphabet, thumb-index

I had the following problem with the index:
The alphabet order of the words in English: I have the order of capital letters come first then the order of small letters come next. I need the order to come according to the letters regardless of being capital or small.
For example:
Abed
Dep
Ced[image]
amid
bned
I need those words to be like:
Abed
amid
bned
Dep
Ced

The next issue is:  I have one gap in the index as shown in the below picture

Comment: A working MWE might help a reader in finding a solution or helpful hints.